Load multiple large CSV files into parquet while creating new colum for file name
I have collections of CSV files, up to 1000, each being ~1 GB uncompressed. I want to create a single parquet dataset from them.
In doing this, I want to record which file each set of rows comes from.
I want to do all this in less than ~10 GB of RAM, in Python.
The obvious place to start was with Dask.
If I do something like:
for infile in file_list:
    ddf = dd.read_csv(infile)
    ddf = ddf.assign(filename=infile)
    ddf.to_parquet("output_parquet_path",
                   append=True,
                   write_index=False,
                   write_metadata_file=True,
                   compute=True)

Then I get an error message about the column types from the second file onwards - it seems that the text columns are of type string[pyarrow] in the parquet file, but object in the Dask dataframe (see ValueError: Appended dtypes differ when appending two simple tables with dask).
If I try to rely on the lazy nature of Dask and do:
frame_list = list()
for infile in file_list:
    ddf = dd.read_csv(infile)
    ddf = ddf.assign(filename=infile)
    frame_list.append(ddf)

full_frame = ddf.concat(frame_list)
full_frame.to_parquet("output_parquet_path",
                   write_index=False,
                   write_metadata_file=True,
                   compute=True)

Then a compute is triggered early and it tries to load all the frames into memory at once.

Is your core issue how to add the column or how to load the 1000 gigs of data?

Have you tried using the include_path_column=True argument in read_csv? Then you don't need the loop/append at all.

@mdurant Thanks - this does seem to be what I'm looking for, although it took me a while to work it out, because the process still uses ~12GB of RAM, even though each file only takes 3.5GB to load in pandas.

Please write a reply to your own question with what you ended up doing, and then accept that as the answer.

The solution was as suggested by @mdurant in the comments - to use the include_path_column=True call in the read_csv command. This adds a new column called path that contains the filename of the csv each row came from.
ddf = dd.read_csv(file_list, include_path_column="filename")
ddf.to_parquet("output_parquet_path",
                write_index=False,
                write_metadata_file=True,
                compute=True)

Its worth noting though that the memory usage is still substantial if your files are gzipped. Dask warns that it can't split gzipped files up and that indevidual files must fit in RAM, but still, memory usage can be more than expected.
For example,  I have files that are 32M compressed, 618M uncompressed, take 3.5GB to load in with pandas, and 5.5GB with the above.
Things increase signficantly if you make any changes. For example, dropping a column:
ddf = dd.read_csv(file_list, include_path_column="filename")
ddf.drop("col1", axis=1).to_parquet("output_parquet_path",
                write_index=False,
                write_metadata_file=True,
                compute=True)

Takes the memory usage up to 8GB.
This is still much better than loading 1000 ~650M dataframes into memory though!
